# Conditionally rename Jackson JSON output

Tags: java, jackson

Let's suppose I have a class holding one variable:

```
@Data
public class Student {
    private List<Grade> allGrades;
}
```

This will be sent to a producer which is written in Python. They would like to have the property in `snake_case` and we want to keep the `camelCase` in java.

This can be achieved with Jackson:

```
@Data
public class Student {
    @JsonProperty("all_grades")
    private List<Grade> allGrades;
}
```

Now, we're building an application that can dynamically switch between producers, so some might be written in Java and some in Python.

In our application we can know this by either storing it in the config or sending it as a request header.

If the producer is Java, we would like to refrain from renaming the property. So the main question is:

**(How) is it possible to conditionally rename the property allGrades to all_grades based on a String/boolean?**

Comment: Maybe the use-case stated is not the best example but the question still stands and has multiple use cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure this is not supported by Jackson out of the box, nor do I think it should be. If you *really* have to do such a thing, you could subclass your `Student` class for different producers, such as

```java
@Data
class Student {
    private List<Grade> allGrades;

    @JsonProperty
    List<Grade> getAllGrades() {
        return allGrades;
    }
}

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
class PythonStudent extends Student {
    @JsonProperty("all_grades")
    @Override
    public void getAllGrades() {
        super.getAllGrades();
    }
}
```

And then construct the desired object based on your condition in a factory class.

That said, it's really easy to consume JSON strings in both Java and Python using either snake_case or camelCase conventions and map them to fields in the desired format. I don't think what you want to achieve adds any value, but it would certainly introduce a lot of complexity.

Comment: Hmm if it's not supported then it does add too much complexity for us. Then we'll have to stick with one of the two and let the producers map the values. Thanks